# SharePoint edit site toolbar ribbon is missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

**I have been struggling with the following issue:** I am trying to edit a SharePoint site, but whenever I click edit, I do not see the ribbon with the Browse and Page menus (the tutorials I have watched have that ribbon!) :(

I have read on the internet that I must switch to classic view, but I just cannot find the option!!!

I have basically installed SharePoint Designer in order to be able to freely edit my site, as I thought this would be the solution, but it is not working either.

I will put some links below with the view I am aiming to obtain:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZO655ZYHhQc
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AeVeji8HFus&t=7s

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the home site page, we cannot see the option to **Return to classic SharePoint** We need to click on any list or library from home site quick launch - then below, we can see the **Return to classic SharePoint** option.

[image: Return to classic SharePoint]

Answer (score 0):

The buttons and the ribbon you are referring to are only available on **classic** pages and lists with classic view.

The page in your screenshot is what the site pages look like today, often referred to as **modern pages**.
There is no way to display these pages in classic view, you must create a new page that is based on the old publishing framework.

To do that you will may need to activate some features to get the old Pages library back:

**Site Collection Feature**
This feature is called "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" and can be found in "Site Collection Features" in Site Settings.

[image]

Site Settings -> Site Features

**Site Feature**
This feature is called "SharePoint Server Publishing" and can be found in "Site Features"

[image]

---

After activating these two features, in the mentioned order, you will find a library called "Pages" under Site Contents:

[image]

This is where you can create classic pages and will get the ribbon you are seeking.

[image]

---